# Azure Service Fabric reset

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, appfabric, service-fabric-on-premises

I am using service fabric locally.

If I stopped debug mode for a couple of mins or restart the computer and continued my work it redeploys the application again from scratch.

How to make it only deploy the changed libraries (which I think it what it should do in the first place)

Answer (score 1):

There is the Application Debug Mode property you can use ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-manage-application-in-visual-studio)):

> Application Debug Modes
>
> 1. Refresh Application This mode enables you to quickly change and debug your code and supports editing static web files while debugging. This mode only works if your local development cluster is in [1-Node mode]. This is the default Application Debug Mode.
> 2. Remove Application causes the application to be removed when the debug session ends.
> 3. Auto Upgrade The application continues to run when the debug session ends. The next debug session will treat the deployment as an upgrade. The upgrade process preserves any data that you entered in a previous debug session.
> 4. Keep Application The application keeps running in the cluster when the debug session ends. At the beginning of the next debug session, the application will be removed.

I think you are looking for option 1 or 3.

You can set the property using the Service Fabric Application project properties.

Comment: Just to clarify, option one will redeploy each time i open VS or if I kept it off debug mode for a couple of mins.(my current case). In Option three I will have to change the version of the code every time I change one line of code ?? -- isn't this weird or there is something I don't understand ?

Comment: P.s. I have used the the third option it redeployed the app without even removing the old version !!!